# Replace concatenation with join

Tags: python, bioinformatics, pysam

I have code which is given below:

```
for pileupcolumn in samfile.pileup(max_depth = 1000000) :
  X.append(pileupcolumn.n)
  for pileupread in pileupcolumn.pileups:
     if (pileupread.alignment.mapping_quality <= 15):
             continue      
     if not pileupread.is_del and not pileupread.is_refskip:
             if pileupread.alignment.query_qualities[pileupread.query_position] < 30:
             # Skip entries with base phred scores < 10
                  continue
             if pileupread.alignment.is_reverse: #negative
                  ReverseList[pileupcolumn.pos] += pileupread.alignment.query_sequence[pileupread.query_position]
             else:
                  ForwardList[pileupcolumn.pos] += pileupread.alignment.query_sequence[pileupread.query_position]
```

The above code is taking a lot of time and I want to replace concatenation   in the 11th and 13th line with join. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the concatenation is using a noticeable amount of time compared to everything else? Using `join` on that is not going to be straight-forward.

Comment: @MarkRansom Since this is bioinformatics, the strings are probably very long (DNA sequences), and repeated concatenation is very likely to be a bottleneck, since it's O(n^2).

Comment: `join` is O(n), because it can allocate the final result string once, and then copy all the inputs into it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating, collect the values into a list, then join the list at the end of the loop.

```
for pileupcolumn in samfile.pileup(max_depth = 1000000) :
  X.append(pileupcolumn.n)
  forward = []
  reverse = []
  for pileupread in pileupcolumn.pileups:
     if (pileupread.alignment.mapping_quality <= 15):
             continue      
     if not pileupread.is_del and not pileupread.is_refskip:
             if pileupread.alignment.query_qualities[pileupread.query_position] < 30:
             # Skip entries with base phred scores < 10
                  continue
             if pileupread.alignment.is_reverse: #negative
                  reverse.append(pileupread.alignment.query_sequence[pileupread.query_position])
             else:
                  forward.append(pileupread.alignment.query_sequence[pileupread.query_position])
  ReverseList[pileupcolumn.pos] += ''.join(reverse)
  ForwardList[pileupcolumn.pos] += ''.join(forward)
```

I still use concatenation at the end, because this optimization only works for the `for pileupread` loop. If different `pileupcolumn` objects have the same `pos`, we need to concatenate at that point. We also need this concatenation if the `ReverseList` elements already have values before this code runs.

Comment: your solution is not working it is giving following error:
  File "getbases.py", line 33, in <module>
    ForwardList,ReverseList = getbases(bamfile)
  File "getbases.py", line 25, in getbases
    ReverseList[pileupcolumn.pos] +=reverse.join()
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That's a problem with the part of the script you didn't show, where `ReverseList` and `ForwardList` are initialized.

Comment: The error means that `pileupcolumn.pos` is bigger than the length of `ReverseList`

Comment: Sorry for that, the two lists i.e ReverseList and ForwardList are initialized with the length of the reference which is can be equal to 16569 or 16571 in following way: ReverseList =[' '] * lenref and ForwardList = [' '] *lenref

Comment: And what's the value of `pileupcolumn.pos` when the error happens?

Comment: My code is assigning to the same element of ReverseList that your code does. I don't see how it could get an error when yours doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156125/discussion-between-ammar-sabir-cheema-and-barmar).

Comment: So previously I was using your solution by creating empty ReverseList and ForwardList but after when I initiated lists with length 16569 as mentioned above: ReverseList =[' '] * lenref and ForwardList = [' '] *lenref then I am getting following error :  ReverseList[pileupcolumn.pos] +=reverse.join() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: Sorry, I was using Javascript join syntax, not Python.

Comment: So is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with my solution once I fixed the incorrect way of calling `join()`?

Comment: If this solution works then there is no issue but its not working

Comment: What problem is it having now? That should have fixed the error about `list object has no attribute join`

Comment: OK let me check it again

Comment: I tried to run it , but the system get hanged after running the above solution.

Comment: I don't see how this can hang, there are no potential infinite loops. But there's no way for me to test it myself. Add print statements so you can see what it's doing.